# setInterval to read text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some troubles to read a number from a text file with JavaScript.

```js
setInterval("readTextFile()", 500);

function readTextFile() {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "zoom.txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = allText;
                writeln(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

The goal is to read a value into `zoom.txt` every `500ms`, but this code doesn't work.
The value from the text file isn't refresh on F5 but only when I open (or refresh) zoom.txt in my browser.

I find something strange, this code works the first time I used it on Midori. Could you help me please ?

Thanks,

EDIT :
 I tried that :

```js
setInterval(readTextFile, 500);
setInterval(test, 500);
function readTextFile()
{
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", "zoom.txt", false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
  {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
      {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = allText;
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
function test(){
  document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '';
}
```

My value is blinking on the screen but don't change even if I modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I empty the cache of Firefox and avoid to use it and the code is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

First parameter to the `setInterval` should be a *function* and not *function call*.

```
setInterval(readTextFile, 500); //No need of quotes
```

Comment: Unless OP uses readTextFile somewhere else he could just put the function anonymously as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If it is fetching the data from the text file on page refresh means that your code is working fine.

Now, you need to change the text in your text file so that it will get new value from the text file.

To check the content every interval you need to empty the html of your div like,

```
function readTextFile() {
    // empty the div first to get the new value from text file
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = '';
    ...
```

Comment: My bad, the value from the text file isn't refresh on F5 but only when I open (or refresh) zoom.txt in my browser :-/